# 'Faulty' Landsat-8 Images (Collection 1 Tier 2) for Antarctica?

Tags: landsat, antarctica

Whilst working with the Landsat collections across Antarctica I have noticed that recent L8 images (from late 2017-present) appear to not be 'correct' in GEE. Images from this time period appear black in the viewer, and when you inspect the pixel values they are all negative (no data). However, images before this time period appear to be fine.

I have checked the Landsat repository in Earth Explorer, and the images seem to hold data, so I am wondering if there is a fault within GEE, or whether I have missed a trick here?

Attached is a simple script, showing a 'working' image and a 'faulty' image. Any advice would be great!

https://code.earthengine.google.com/14c0b1c5bf61bc40627a3133cd9c1116

Comment: Please include a code snippet within your question rather than s link to code.